# Flex, zend production error

Tags: apache-flex, zend-framework, flex4

I've got my flex, php & zend project working fine on localhost but when I try to move it to production I get the following error:

```
Class "testService" does not exist: Plugin by name 'testService' was not found in the registry; used     
paths:
: /home/myNewFolder/services/
#0 /home/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Amf/Server.php(550): Zend_Amf_Server->_dispatch('paged', Array,     
'testService')
#1 /home/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Amf/Server.php(626): Zend_Amf_Server-   
>_handle(Object(Zend_Amf_Request_Http))
#2 /home/myNewFolder/gateway.php(69): Zend_Amf_Server->handle()
#3 {main}
```

I've got my amf_config file as follows:

```
[zend]
webroot =/home/myNewFolder
zend_path =/home/ZendFramework/library
[zendamf]
amf.production = false
amf.directories[]=services
```

my .swf & services folder are located in "myNewFolder", which is located under the root of my directory.

I am using Zend version 1.9.4, Flex SDK 4.1. My localhost is windows & production host is Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two potential problems, the home on the server is not the path you think. Print home to screen to see what is there. Second, always, always use small letters. Too many problems arise when you write myApp, MyApp or Myapp. just write myapp, and do not worry again

Edit: wait a second, your services path is wrong. I assume it is under New Folder. Your amf directories should change to amf.directories[]=./services

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Unix is case sensitive, and Windows doesn't so check the case, your file should be named testService.php, or TestService.php.